# How can I use Heavy fonts in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the font "Avenir Next Heavy" in XAML.

`FontAttributes` does not have an option for Heavy, so I imported a `.ttf` file with "Avenir Next Heavy". Despite only containing the Heavy font, the `.ttf` file showed as a normal font, and did not display the "Heavy" option in `FontAttributes`.

Comment: I tried both of the above. Your first link teaches about font attributes and the like. Unfortunately that does not help as FontAttributes only allows for Normal, Bold, and Italic. Heavy is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @FabriBertani as my question details I tried to add the custom font but I still could not access its Heavy attribute, despite the font being a heavy font.

Comment: since you don't have `Heavy` attribute you could create a custom one and add it or get a `.ttf` only with the heavy one

Comment: That's what I did

Comment: It didn't work sadly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the FontFamily instead of FontAttributes. If you read this article https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/ there you can see that they are creating the Style like BoldFont, NormalFont and mapping their custom font with that Style.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="HeavyFont">
        <On Platform="Android" Value="YourFont-Heavy.ttf#YourFont" />
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Bold" />
    </OnPlatform>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="RegularFont">
        <On Platform="Android" Value="YourFont-Regular.ttf#YourFont" />
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Regular" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

While creating your Label or while setting the font you will do like :

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Helloworld heavy" FontFamily="{StaticResource HeavyFont}" />
    <Label text="Helloworld normal" FontFamily="{StaticResource NormalFont}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Make sure to add your fonts in platform specific projects. If you follow that article you should be good. Resource Dictionary, you can define this in App.Xaml if you want to define that in Global scope or directly inside your ContentPage/View if you just need that in that scope.

**Update : If you are using Xamarin.Forms 4.5.530 and up**
- there's new update in Xamarin forms to support Embedded Fonts. You are right, you don't have to copy paste the fonts into your platform specifics and try to find the Android, iOS Font Family name - You can simply use the Embedded font file name and specify the any Alias name you want to call that font:

- Copy the Fonts into any directory into your shared project.
- Register the font as like below:

  [assembly: ExportFont("Rukmini-bold.ttf", Alias = "MyRukminiBoldFont")]

That's it. You can now use the Font as you were using before. [Here's the link to detailed explanation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/) if you are having trouble.

Comment: You should exactly match the font name including the text after # symbol "YourFont-Heavy.ttf#YourFont" in android.

Comment: Decided to use a different file for my font (.ttf) and suddenly it works. Thanks Nirmal.

Comment: As of Xamarin.Forms 4.5.530 and up, there is no need to specify platform, nor add the font files to each of the native projects.  Here is a great guide https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @chri3g91 You are right. I will update the answers just in case if someone else searches. Thank you for the info.